# Facebook Application development language problem

Tags: facebook, fbml

what i want is, suppose that my facebook language is spanish then my application open is in spanish else open in default in english . how can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use [FQL](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Standard_user_info_%28FQL%29) and [Locales](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Locales) under [standard_user_info](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Standard_user_info_%28FQL%29)

> **locale**     *string* -- The two-letter
>   language code and the two-letter
>   country code representing the user's
>   locale. Country codes are taken from
>   the ISO 3166 alpha 2 code list.

Comment: Thanks Matthew i am searching for the exact

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a desk app to talk to Facebook? Or are you talking about an ASP.NET app. You want to localice your application depending on the facebook language, is this right?

Im sorry! I misunderstood the question.-

Perhaps you can find usefull information here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Internationalization